# jQuery Autocomplete with custom renderer throwing "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'd like to display the suggestions in a table, it works but throws a JS error when hovering over the static table header. How do I fix this? It works perfectly otherwise.

[image]

**Error Steps:**

[image]

*Note: it used to work in jquery 1.10.4 but throws error when I tried upgrading to 1.12.4*

**Working version** **(on 1.10.4):** https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/bq526h67/1/

**Version throwing error** **(on 1.12.4):** https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/L52u064j/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="project-label">Select a project (type "s" for a start):</div>
<input id="project">
<input type="hidden" id="project-id">
<p id="project-description"></p>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  //random json values
  var projects =  [{ id: 1, value: "Thomas", cp: 134 }, { id: 65, value: "Richard", cp: 1743 }, { id: 235, value: "Harold", cp: 7342 }, { id: 78, value: "Santa Maria", cp: 787 }, { id: 75, value: "Gunner", cp: 788 }, { id: 124, value: "Shad", cp: 124 }, { id: 1233, value: "Aziz", cp: 3544 }, { id: 244, value: "Buet", cp: 7847 }];



  // define UI behavior methods

  function _renderMenu(ul, items) {
    var self = this;
    //table definitions
    ul.append("<table border=1><thead><tr><th>ID#</th><th>Name</th><th>Cool&nbsp;Points</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
      self._renderItemData(ul, ul.find("table tbody"), item);
    });
  }

  function _renderItemData(ul, table, item) {
    return this._renderItem(table, item).data("ui-autocomplete-item", item);
  };

  function _renderItem(table, item) {
    return $("<tr class='ui-menu-item' role='presentation'></tr>")
      //.data( "item.autocomplete", item )
      .append("<td >" + item.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.value + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.cp + "</td>")
      .appendTo(table);
  };



  // create the autocomplete
  var autocomplete = $("#project").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: projects
  });

  // get a handle on it's UI view
  var autocomplete_handle = autocomplete.data("ui-autocomplete");

  //overriding jquery-ui.autocomplete .js functions
  autocomplete_handle._renderMenu = _renderMenu;
  autocomplete_handle._renderItemData = _renderItemData;
  autocomplete_handle._renderItem = _renderItem;

});
```

Comment: SO should really not allow downvotes without comments. Can the downvoter provide feedback so my question can be better?

Comment: Both version work fine when I tried them.  Neither one throws an error on hover or otherwise.

Comment: @Guest I have updated the links and added a gif to show the error.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar I get the following error in FF: `TypeError: ui.item is undefined[Learn More] _display:139:5,  _doFocusStuff https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:139:5`

Comment: @Twisty I get the error even if remove the focus handler:  

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/L52u064j/2/

Comment: I think the `thead` is confusing the focus. Since it's being rendered as an item; I think when you focus upon it, it does not have any item data; triggering the console error. Investigating more.

Comment: @Twisty exactly, but the thing seems to work on the older jquery! Thank you for taking a look

Comment: Working with this as a test: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/192m0uyc/ So far it works; I still get an odd error when the `thead` is interacted with, but it's now not a show stopper.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you, your solution works (the arrow key notwithstanding). I took your suggestions on board and implemented a solution that also with works with the arrow keys. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATE] Working Solution based on Twisty's code and Lambrusco's suggestion:**

- I made the header as full "item" (with backing object) on the widget,
  so the `arrow` handler has an "item" to process when it focuses on it.
- And I added an identifying property on the header object to allow the
  renderer to render it differently.
- I also changed the code to be `DIV/CSS` grid based rather than true `TABLEs`, with each "row" being a proper `LI` so we dont get the complete mess of tables inside `UL` tags.

**Working Code:**

```
$(function() {
  //random json values
  var projects = [{../*commented for brevity*/..}];

  $.widget("custom.tablecomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      this._super();
      this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> li:not(.ui-autocomplete-header)");
    },
    _renderMenu(ul, items) {
      var self = this;
      ul.addClass("container");

      let header = {
        id: "IP",
        value: "VALUE",
        cp: "CP",
        isheader: true
      };
      self._renderItemData(ul, header);
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        self._renderItemData(ul, item);
      });

    },
    _renderItemData(ul, item) {
      return this._renderItem(ul, item).data("ui-autocomplete-item", item);
    },
    _renderItem(ul, item) {
      var $li = $("<li class='ui-menu-item' role='presentation'></li>");
      if (item.isheader)
        $li = $("<li class='ui-autocomplete-header' role='presentation'  style='font-weight:bold !important;'></li>");
      var $content = "<div class='row ui-menu-item-wrapper'>" + "<div class='col-xs-3'>" + item.id + "</div>" + "<div class='col-xs-5'>" + item.value + "</div>" + "<div class='col-xs-3'>" + item.cp + "</div>" + "</div>";
      $li.html($content);


      return $li.appendTo(ul);
    }

  });



  // create the autocomplete
  var autocomplete = $("#project").tablecomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: projects,
  });

  // get a handle on it's UI view
  var autocomplete_handle = autocomplete.data("ui-autocomplete");
});
```

**Fiddle :**

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/j7fu060j/

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it up with the help of the `$.widget()` builder.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/192m0uyc/2/

**Widget**

```
$.widget("custom.tablecomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> tr:not(.ui-autocomplete-header)");
  },
  _renderMenu(ul, items) {
    var self = this;
    var $t = $("<table>", {
      border: 1
    }).appendTo(ul);
    $t.append($("<thead>"));
    $t.find("thead").append($("<tr>", {
      class: "ui-autocomplete-header"
    }));
    var $row = $t.find("tr");
    $("<th>").html("ID#").appendTo($row);
    $("<th>").html("Name").appendTo($row);
    $("<th>").html("Cool Point").appendTo($row);
    $("<tbody>").appendTo($t);
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
      self._renderItemData(ul, $t.find("tbody"), item);
    });
  },
  _renderItemData(ul, table, item) {
    return this._renderItem(table, item).data("ui-autocomplete-item", item);
  },
  _renderItem(table, item) {
    var $row = $("<tr>", {
      class: "ui-menu-item",
      role: "presentation"
    });
    $("<td>").html(item.id).appendTo($row);
    $("<td>").html(item.value).appendTo($row);
    $("<td>").html(item.cp).appendTo($row);
    return $row.appendTo(table);
  }
});
```

Using the http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories example, we can override the rendering as you wanted and leverage the strength of the widget builder. This basically ignores the `thead` now as a category versus an item the user might interact with. The rest of the usage is copied over from `$.ui.autocomplete` so it works the same.

One minor caveat, if the user presses <kbd>↓</kbd> the `thead` is found, generating an error. This does not prevent further action and is passive.

Comment: I upvoted you for good solution, but really I think it's bad idea to implement it as table at all, we can easily mock table layout with css instead. 

In the end, we get table wrapped in ul, what a complete mess)

Comment: @Lambrusco I totally agree. `table` should not be used. It's not what OP asked though.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you, i have tried to fix the arrow key problem with my solution based on yours. I have accepted my own answer with the intention that future passersby would use that as it is the more complete solution both DOM structure and widget behavior-wise. I realize you only stuck to the table-based solution because of the scope of the question (and would have done LIs otherwise). So please let me know if you think that  "accepting" my answer seems unfair to you and I will happily revert and accept yours.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar *shrug* it's just points and we're all working toward helpful solutions, so whatever is clever.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer. First, there are differencies between versions 1.10.4 and 1.12.4 of autocomplete, so it's not strange that they behave differently.

Second, you override menu building, but you don't override menu selection, so if we will see debug data

```
        menufocus: function(e, i) {
            var s, n;
            return this.isNewMenu && (this.isNewMenu = !1,
            e.originalEvent && /^mouse/.test(e.originalEvent.type)) ? (this.menu.blur(),
            this.document.one("mousemove", function() {
                t(e.target).trigger(e.originalEvent)
            }),
            void 0) : (n = i.item.data("ui-autocomplete-item"),
            !1 !== this._trigger("focus", e, {
                item: n
            }) && e.originalEvent && /^key/.test(e.originalEvent.type) && this._value(n.value),
            s = i.item.attr("aria-label") || n.value,
            s && t.trim(s).length && (this.liveRegion.children().hide(),
            t("<div>").text(s).appendTo(this.liveRegion)),
            void 0)
        },
```

The string

```
s = i.item.attr("aria-label") || n.value
```

Gives us error, cause as we see earlier

```
n = i.item.data("ui-autocomplete-item")
```

And it is undefined

You can just to check in your focus function if it is header and skip it, cause autocomplete expects item to have ui-autocomplete-item data as you see.

Comment: Thelambofgoat could you elaborate more on how to check if it's the header?

Comment: I simply added check: label = ui.item.attr( "aria-label" ) || (item?item.value:'');